# How to break line in PHP request to Pivotal Tracker API

Tags: php, html, api, markup, pivotaltracker

Pivotal Tracker doesn't accept \r\n character in it's request, and 
 will just be displayed in the story description.

How do I add new line in the PHP string to be submitted in the API?

Answer (score 0):

You try \n inside double coats ex:  `"\n"`